# Dynamic Tooltip Text amChart

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have a Gantt chart made with amCharts and it works fine. 
As showed below, I set the TooltipText from my ColumnSeries.

```
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series1.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
series1.columns.template.tooltipText = "Load nº: {Load}\nStart: {openDateX}\nEnd: {dateX}\nType: {PartType}";
```

This part is OK. But now I need dynamically change the TooltipText according to an rule. I read on the documentation about the adapters and i wrote this code.

```
series1.columns.template.adapter.add('getTooltipText', function(text, target) {
    var data = target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext;
    if (data.Load != null )
       return "Load nº: {data.Load}\nStart: {data.openDateX}\nEnd: {data.dateX}\nType: {data.PartType}";
    else
        return "Start: {data.openDateX}\nEnd: {data.dateX}";
});
```

But this code is not working. 
The Tooltip doesn't appear anymore. What I'm doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Real close!

If you've seen [`getTooltipText`, that was probably for Axis Tooltips](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/?s=gettooltiptext).

For your columns, just `tooltipText` ought to do it, so try this instead:

```js
series1.columns.template.adapter.add('tooltipText', function(text, target) {
    var data = target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext;
    if (data.Load != null )
       return "Load nº: {Load}\nStart: {openDateX}\nEnd: {dateX}\nType: {PartType}";
    else
        return "Start: {openDateX}\nEnd: {dateX}";
});
```

Also note I didn't nest the data above via `data.fieldName`, just `fieldName`. [Check out our guide on Data to learn more about how the charts determine where to look for `fieldName`, i.e. string placeholders.](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Data_source)

In the demo below I use this:

```js
series.columns.template.adapter.add('tooltipText', function(text, target) {
    var data = target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext;
    if (data.Load != null )
       return "Load nº: {categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
    else
        return "Start: {categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
});
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ea9f73243aed2d62b768ad168a2e1dcc

This works with the Chart Cursor (`am4charts.XYCursor`), too.

Comment: i tried this one, and added console log inside, so my question, is it normal that console log run 4 time? when i hover the template i get 4 result of console log, i want to make api request on hover the template and return a value depend of api result; so i'm afraid to make it run 4 request at same time

Comment: In amcharts v5 you should change 'adapter' to 'adapters', and  'tooltipDataItem' to 'dataItem'